# Have to refresh web page to function when using jquery functions with react application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, react-router

I'm  writing ReactJS application. For ease of use for styling & responsiveness, I'm using HTML5 theme called '**CANVAS HTML5 Theme**', which uses jQuery functions for animations, siders and modals. This is how intergrate them in `index.html`:

```
<head> <link... [css stylesheets related to theme are here] /> </head>

<body class="stretched  side-panel-left sticky-responsive-menu">
   <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
      <noscript> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app </noscript>
      <div id="root" class="section nomargin nopadding"></div>
   </div>

   <script src=".././js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src=".././js/plugins.js"></script>
   <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
         $('.read-more-target').hide();
      });
</body>
```

Here, reactjs application is injected with `id=root` tag and all `jquery` functions related to the theme are in the `<body>` as well. (NOTE: I know that using two DOM manipulatinng libraries are not a good practise, but used this way to get a head-start.)

Issue I'm facing is as follows: I'm using button in header to open up side panel in the web page.

```
$('.side-panel-trigger').click(function () {
   $('body').addClass('side-panel-open');
});
```

At the button click of `side-panel-trigger`, it'll add `side-panel-open` class to `<body>` tag, which in return would open up side panel from left side. (In chrome dev tools, if I'add `side-panel-open` class to `<body>`, it'll open)
**However when I click mentioned button it would not open up the side panel.** (`<body class=...>` seems to change from DOM inspection, but instantly reverted back to open without `side-panel-open`). **However when I refresh the page and click this button, it'll open up side panel every time.**
This might be not only related to sidepanel since, in some pages animations doesn't seems to start, but when I refresh it'll start animation immediately. (Seems jquery functions are not applied to react, mainly when routed with react-router. Refresh seems to function everything, but I don't want to add refresh since it'll slow done application.)

Is there a solution to solve this. Should `id=root` react application should be in a different place? Can I add jquery functions and all js files into react application somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach your event on always existing element:

```
$('body').on('click','.side-panel-trigger', function () {
   $('body').addClass('side-panel-open');
});
```